# Does $X\setminus\emptyset=X$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty set, my question is the following:

> Is $X\setminus\emptyset=X$?

Instinctively, if you take off the null set from a non-empty set, it won't change anything but the null set is included in every set so if you "take it off" you ultimately change the set.

Comment: Have you tried proving the equality by mutual subset inclusion?

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow I encounter the same problem

Comment: What do you mean by 'the null set is included in every set'? It's certainly not an element of every set.

Comment: @DanRust I'm not sure OP understands the difference between being an element of a set versus a subset of a set...which would make a proof by showing mutual subset inclusion rather difficult.

Comment: @aribaldi: No, you don’t change the set. You are removing from $X$ the *elements* of $\varnothing$, and there are no such elements, so you’re not removing anything from $X$ at all.

Comment: Perhaps an example is the best way to illustrate this. What is $\{1,2,3\}\setminus \{\}$ ? (here I'm using the notation $\emptyset = \{\}$ as it illustrates the operation of $\setminus$ slightly more clearly)

Comment: I am amazed at the fact that the empty set generates such an abundance of comments :)

Comment: The emptyset is a subset of $X$ (for any $X$) but the operation of "subtraction" acts on the *elements* of the sets : $X \setminus Y$ is "manufactured" throwing away from $X$ the elements belonging to $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Instinctively, if you take off the null set from a non-empty set, it won't change anything but the null set is included in every set"

It's time to whack you on the head with a 2 by 4.  (Don't worry; we all get whacked in the head once in a while.)

"take off the null set".  What does "take off" mean?  If I said "take off 2 from the set {1,2,3,4,5}" does it mean the same thing as "take off {2} from the set of {1,2,3,4,5}" and what if instead I said "take of {2} from {$\mathbb R$, $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb Z$, {1,2,3,4,5},  {0,2,5,6,......}, {odd numbers}}" what would that *mean*?

Important thing to realize is a *set* as an object is a different thing than then it's elements.  $\{2\} \subset \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ but $\{2\} \not \subset \{\mathbb R, \mathbb Q, \mathbb Z, \{1,2,3,4,5\},\{2\}  \{0,2,5,6,......\}, \{odd numbers\}\}$ even though $\{2\} \in  \{\mathbb R, \mathbb Q, \mathbb Z, {1,2,3,4,5},\{2\} \{0,2,5,6,.....\}, \{odd numbers\}\}$.  This is because $\{2\}$-- the set with a single element; 2-- is a different thing than $\{\{2\}\}$-- the set with a single element; the set with element 2$.

"but the null set is included in every set"

That is an ambiguous poorly formed sentence and is wrong by most accepted mathematical language.

The null set is a set with no elements.  A subset of a set is a set whose elements are all in the other set.  As the null set has *no* elements, they are all elements of any other set (all zero of them) so the null set is a subset of every set.

But "is included" usually does not mean "is a subset of" but instead means "is an element of". S=  {banana, $\pi$, $\sqrt{27}$} is a set with three elements.  None of them is the null set. so $\emptyset \not \in S$.

R = {banana, {1,2,3,4,5}, $\emptyset$, $\pi$}.  Then $banana \in R$,  $\{1,2,3,4,5\} \in R$, $\pi \in R$.  $\emptyset \in R$.  $\{2,4,5\} \not \in R$.

So, no, the null set "is a subset" of every set, but the null set is not "included" in every set.

So..... What does $A\setminus B$ mean.  It means $\{a| a\in B; a \not \in B\}$ so $X\setminus \emptyset = \{x \in X; x \not \in \emptyset\}$ but as *ALL* $x \not \in \emptyset$,  $\{x \in X; x \not \in \emptyset\}= \{x \in X\} = X$.  So **YES**, $X\setminus \emptyset = X$.

**BUT**  if $R = \{banana, \{1,2,3,4,5\}, \emptyset, \pi\}$ then $R \setminus \{\emptyset\} = \{banana, \{1,2,3,4,5\},  \pi\}\ne R$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $X \backslash \emptyset = \{ x | x \in X$ and $x \notin \emptyset \}$. Clearly, then, if $x \in X$ we have $x \in X \backslash \emptyset$ and vice versa. Intuitively, $X \backslash \emptyset$ is everything in $X$ except elements of $\emptyset$, of which there are none.

Answer (score 0):

$A\setminus B$ is the set of all **elements** that belong to $A$ and not belong to $B$ and, if $B=\emptyset$ there are no elements that belong to $B$, so $A\setminus B$ is the set of all elements that belong to $A$.